# Error - Service is unavailable at this time while accessing the images from digital ocean space?

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

***I'm getting this error when I try to access the images from digital ocean space :***

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>ServiceUnavailable</Code>
<Message>Service is unavailable at this time.</Message>
</Error>
```